# Grails web.xml edits - filter-mapping order not preserved

Tags: grails

I ran `grails install-templates` and edited the `web.xml` to add a few servlet filters.  What I can't understand is why the filter mappings are getting re-ordered.

`GRAILS_WORK/projects/myproject/web.xml.tmp` has filters in the right order (A, B, C, D, E)
but `GRAILS_WORK/projects/myproject/resources/web.xml` is wrong (E, B, D, A, C)

What would cause them to be re-ordered?  Why wouldn't the `web.xml` template edits carry through to my application verbatim?

Comment: possible related issue, https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8799 - although no one on that thread discussed editing web.xml directly

Comment: What version of Grails you are using? 2.x or 3.x ? I have a problem with webxml plugin during migration to Grails 3

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Some plugins like cache and resources depend on the webxml plugin, and the published version has a defect where `findFilterMappingNames` in `_Events.groovy` returns a `Set`, instead of a `List`.  So the original ordering of the filter mappings is lost at that point.

It looks like there is a version on GitHub where this is fixed, but I'm not sure how to get my project to use that particular version, especially when it's being included via other plugin dependencies

(version with fixes: https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-webxml/blob/master/scripts/_Events.groovy)